# How to change default bounce back address?

Tags: centos, postfix

I have postfix server running on centos 6 server i have 3 user on my server when they send mails using my server and all 3 users bounce address are different by default in postfix now i want to store all users bounce back mails should come on a single user mailbox on another or same server such as user@mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread might be helpful for you, as i dont think there is a way to change the default Reply-To address in postfix, but if you are sending emails from other clients, like php or mailx,then you can change the Return path.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965986/preventing-delivery-status-notification-errors-or-email-replys

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667620/specifying-the-bounce-back-address-for-email

Answer (score 1):

The [bounce address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_address) is taken from the SMTP envelope from address provided by the client. This is usually the same as the RFC2822 from address in the message header, but it doesn't have to be. For example, in the following message submission the bounce address will be "bounces@example.com" and not "bob@example.com":

```
> EHLO mamma.local
< 250 mail.example.com
> MAIL FROM: bounces@example.com
< 250 OK
> RCPT TO: alice@example.com
< 250 OK
> DATA
< 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
> From: bob@example.com
> To: alice@example.com
> ...
> .
< 250 OK: queued as 12345
```

To change it you need to reconfigure the mail user agent sending the message in the first place, and not the mail transfer agent (Postfix in this case). How you do that depends on what is sending the messages.